# How to display multiple combination of Bands using Leaflet js?

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, leaflet, satellite

My question has 2 parts. 
Can I get/set (access) the Image pixel values ( DN of each band ) through leaflet js? If not can any one tell me, how to tinker with the band combination of the image display if using ImageOverlay (or if there are any other methods to display a satellite image in browser ). I am currently working to display hyperion data (with roughly 260 bands) in browser but I want to display a certain selected band combination to be displayed through leaflet. I am sure this must be possible , but I just can't get my brain to do it.

- I know that ESRI has a public API. But it only works for ARC GIS Services

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [Leaflet.TileLayer.GL](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL). It's a `L.TileLayer` rather than a `L.ImageOverlay`, but allows you to mix and match pixel values from different raster sources, as long as those sources can be loaded into Leaflet by means of a `L.TileLayer`. If you look at some of the examples, you'll see a NDWI calculation based on false colour iRGB imagery.

Please bear in mind that the API key for the imagery services is not valid and those examples are sadly not functional. Also note that it uses WebGL, so you'll need to code your pixel calculations in GLSL, which might look like an alien programming language if you're never seen it (reading the [book of shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/) will be helpful).

Comment: Thanks for the response Ivan. I am also trying to handle imagery without any geo -referencing. I doubt if I can create any Tile layer for such imagery without Geo CRS. Do you have any method in mind to handle such cases. One note is that , The data to be accessed is always directly available to the machine (if that would help? )

Comment: TileLayer.GL is CRS-agnostic, so you could use `L.CRS.Simple`. Just make sure to slice your raster images into tiles that can be loaded with a `L.TileLayer` - see questions about `gdal2tiles` and the like. And keep in mind that WebGL is troublesome when loading images from a `file://` URI - consider running a webserver in localhost.